# How to map prediction output of keras model built from data generator (flow_from_directories)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have two CSV files, "train.csv" and "test.csv", which looks something like this

| Image_ID | Target |
| --- | --- |
| ID_7xd1 | 0 |
| ID_8xk1 | 1 |

This is the example of train.csv, in test.csv I have just the `Image_ID` column and the goal is to predict its target with the images provided. The images folder are as follows

```sh
Images
├── test
│   ├── ID_12ls.tif
│   └── ID_1sfk.tif
│   └── ...
└── train
    ├── 0
    │   ├── ID_7xd1.tif
    │   └── ID_9xd0.tif
    │   └──...
    └── 1
        ├── ID_0xkd0.tif
        └── ID_8xdk1.tif
        └── ...
```

---

Each Image_ID in train.csv and test.csv represent an image and is tracked by the name of the image itself. Since I had lots of images so I decided to use Keras `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directories`

```py
# data generators
datagen_train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.2, )
datagen_test = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# load and iterate training dataset
train_it = datagen_train.flow_from_directory('train/', target_size= (224, 224), class_mode='binary', batch_size=64, seed=0, subset='training')

# load and iterate validation dataset
val_it = datagen_train.flow_from_directory('train/', target_size= (224, 224), class_mode='binary', batch_size=64, seed=0, subset='validation')

# load and iterate test dataset
test_it = datagen_test.flow_from_directory('test/', target_size = (224, 224), class_mode=None, batch_size=1, seed=0)
```

model

```py
model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Conv2D(32,3,padding="valid", activation="relu", input_shape=(224,224,3)))
model2.add(MaxPool2D())
model2.add(Dropout(0.4))

model2.add(Flatten())
model2.add(Dense(128,activation="relu"))
model2.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.000001)
model2.compile(optimizer = opt , loss = 'binary_crossentropy' , metrics = ['accuracy'])

# callbacks
mc_loss = ModelCheckpoint('model2svd.h5', monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

history2 = model2.fit_generator(generator=train_it, steps_per_epoch=step_size_t, validation_data= val_it, validation_steps=step_size_v,
                               epochs=100, shuffle=True, callbacks=[mc_loss])
```

#### Problem

Now after training the model with `model.fit_generator()`, I made prediction on the testing dataset with `model.predict_generator()`. It gave me array of `1,m` where m is total examples.

The problem is how do I map this output with my test.csv Image_ID. Or is the output is in the order of test.csv's Image_ID.

please let me know me if you need more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your test generator set shuffle=False. Also model.predict_generator is depreciated so just use model.predict. Now with shuffle=False in test generaotr you can get the sequence of predicted image files in the order they were processed as

```
test_files=test_it.filenames
```

to ensure you go through the test set samples EXACTLY once determine the test batch size and test steps such that test_batch_size X test_steps= number of test samples
using the code below:

```
length=len(test_files)
test_batch_size=sorted([int(length/n) for n in range(1,length+1) if length % n ==0 and length/n<=80],reverse=True)[0]  
test_steps=int(length/test_batch_size)
print ( 'test batch size: ' ,test_batch_size, '  test steps: ', test_steps)
```

then do

```
preds=model.predict(test_it, batch_size=test_batch_size, steps=test_steps)
```

then iterate through the preds

```
labels=[]
for  p in preds:    
    if p > .5:
        label=1
    else:
        label=0
    labels.append(label)
Fseries=pd.Series(test_files, name='Image Id')
Lseries=pd.Series(labels, name='Target')
predictions_df= pd.concat([Fseries, Lseries], axis=1)

print (predictions_df.head())
```

Comment: Awesome love the answer, thanks for pointing out the changing the `shuffle` parameter.  I just want to understand a little bit more about your second step, what are we trying to do, actually I am just getting started with computer vision and I have very little ideas about Keras ImageDataGenerator.

Comment: Okay, but since the `test_step` went to be 40, it is predicting the values for only 40 items. I got this `Length of values (40) does not match the length of index (3000)` while trying to add the target column. Previously I kept `batch_size` as 1 and `step_size as = test_it.n//test_it.batch_size`. Is it good to go with this?

Comment: In the second step I want to determine the batch size and number of test steps so that batch size  X test steps= number of samples in the test set. Using these values in model.predict ensures that you predict on all the samples in the test set EXACTLY once. For example assume you have 100 samples  and you set the batch size to 10 and test steps to 11. You would predict 110 samples. Lets say the first sample is predicted incorrectly but all 99 other are predicted correctly. The sample with the error would be processed twice and give you a false error rate of 2/110 versus 1/100.

Comment: set the batch_size=test_batch_size and steps=test_steps as calculated by the code

Comment: I tried your batch_size and steps values
pred = model3.predict(test_it, batch_size=test_batch_size, steps=test_steps)
sub = pd.DataFrame()
sub['Image_ID'] = [x[3:14] for x in test_files] # 3000 values
sub['Target'] = pred
sub.head()
But its giving me error that sub_target only has 40 values

Comment: As you stated batch_size X step_size needs to be equal to the total number of examples. Then could we set batch_size =1 and step_size = 3000(total no of example). Is this large number of step_size acceptable?

Comment: yep it will work. For example if the number of samples is a prime number the answer is batch_size=1 test steps =no of samples